# Sails.js doesn't work, 'sails' is not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package, sails.js

**'sails' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

So basically I use Windows 10 and I need Sails up and running. I saw on YT people working with that with no problems. I really wanna use Sails.js because it's amazing but I cannot use it.

I don't know what's wrong. I'm doing everything like they say to do. I've installed it globally through npm and of course, I have Node installed and still, I have that error...

What should I do?

Comment: The important question is.. Did you `npm install sails -g`?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings of course, I'll edit the question, I've installed it globally and still, doesn't work

Comment: If you have installed node and sails successfully. You should also have a Node.js command prompt you can run. Try running sails from the Node.js command prompt instead. Your first command should be; sails new project where project is the name of your project. If sails is still unrecognised, you could try uninstalling and reinstalling sails with npm.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the path to the sails script in the PATH environment variable. What you can do is find where your sails have been installed:

```
dir sails.cmd /s
```

After you find it, open windows menu and type directly 'env' and then select 'Edit the system environment variables'. In the opened window click on the 'Environment variables...' button and add the path to the 'Path' variable.

However, a more preferable way is to uninstall everything (node included) and use the nvm (Node Version Manager) program to get the node itself. You can find it here:

```
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases
```

Then use it to get the node version you want. It is a very useful tool to quickly change between node versions. After that install sails as usual and you should be good to go.